# Where does output of table stored using mysql in Batch mode?

Tags: mysql

I am beginner in mysql. I want to store the output of a table in a file. I wrote following query:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < /home/yati/Desktop/document_Óbuda/semesterIV/DBMS/batch > mysql.out
```

Here, batch is the text file where i stored following queries:

```
USE testdb;
SELECT * FROM pet;
```

Here, testdb is my database and pet is the name of the table. After, inputing my password, it didn't show the path, where the table is stored. If i omit mysql.out, then output is displayed in the command prompt as shown:
[image]
Please help?

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't show the path"? If you print the content of mysql.out (`cat mysql.out`) doesn't it contain what you need?

Comment: My question is where to find the file which contains the table because i cannot see any output in my command prompt.

Comment: If you redirect the output of a command to a file, you won't see that output in the terminal. The file you are looking for is in the current directory and is called mysql.out. So if you do `cat mysql.out` you will see the results.

Comment: I can see my table using this query in command prompt. But i want to store this output in a text file then which query will i use?